# Copy path from nerd tree on click

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

How is it possible to do this?

I would like the path to paste it in command mode with CTRL-R.

Comment: you could also try this plugin i've put together based on NERDTree ([Vimpanel](https://github.com/mihaifm/vimpanel)). Press `ff` on any node to copy its path.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the plugin's own extension system for custom mappings; there's even a example given at `:help NERDTreeAddKeyMap()` that almost does what you want.

Just put the following fragment into `~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/yank_mapping.vim`:

```
call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({
        \ 'key': '<LeftMouse>',
        \ 'callback': 'NERDTreeYankCurrentNode',
        \ 'quickhelpText': 'put full path of current node into the default register' })

function! NERDTreeYankCurrentNode()
    execute "normal! \<LeftMouse>"
    let n = g:NERDTreeFileNode.GetSelected()
    if n != {}
        call setreg('"', n.path.str())
    endif
endfunction
```

---

**Previous answer** (without the NERDTree Keymap API)

You could inject a small function at the end of `plugin/NERD_tree.vim` to get access to the script's internals:

```
function! GetSelected()
    return s:TreeFileNode.GetSelected()
endfunction
```

Then, the modification (you can put them in the same place) would be:

```
:autocmd FileType nerdtree
\    nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <LeftMouse>
\    <LeftMouse>:silent! call setreg('"', GetSelected().path.str())<CR>
```

Comment: Can you explain me this command? it would work without changing anything to NERDTree or something like that?

Comment: Sorry, I had answered a TagBar-related question just before, and my brain hadn't switched yet. After one crude attempt, I found a way to implement this without modifying the NERDTree plugin. Please see my edits.

Comment: It would work if I don't have NERDTree installed at ~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin?

Comment: I copied this code in `~/.vim/janus/vim/tools/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin`, because that folder was already created, then I sourced the file `so path_to_yank_mapping.vim`. Did not work, maybe my configuration is too specific, actually I can't make a lot of plugins work although some others work. I don't understand very well VIM paths and scripts.

Comment: Many people here recommend against distributions like _Janus_. They're supposed to make things easier, but in fact often complicate the setup due to their own complexities.

Comment: Put the script into the folder that contains `exec_menuitem.vim` and `fs_menu.vim`; these come with NERDTree. No need to `:source`, the plugin does that. Now, maybe these built-in add-ons don't work with Janus, neither; try with a plain `~/.vim` structure. I'm now using a script similar to what I posted (just using keys instead of the mouse), and it works just fine.